# Jquery show / hide div onclick radiobutton - not working at all

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm spent hours and hours and already try everything I could find on net. Nothing works!

As the title, I need to simple show / hide a div when i the radio is clicked. I tested replacing the radiobuttons with links and worked! But with radiobutton nothing

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.div_entrega_outro').hide();
    $("input[id$='entrega_outro']").click(function() {
        $('.div_entrega_outro').show();
    });

    $("input[id$='entrega_mesmo']").click(function() {
        $('.div_entrega_outro').hide();
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<input name="outro_endereco_entrega" id="entrega_mesmo" type="radio" value="N" > <label for="InputName">Entregar no endereço de cadastro</label><br>
<input name="outro_endereco_entrega" id="entrega_outro" type="radio" value="S" > <label for="InputName">Entregar em outro endereço</label>

<div class="div_entrega_outro" >
    bla bla bla
</div
```

What I alredy tried:

```
if($('input:radio[name=outro_endereco_entrega]:checked').val() == "N") 

$('#entrega_mesmo').click(function ()
```

Links tests:

[link1](http://www.sencial.com.br/teste/teste_radio_1.html) / 
[link2](http://www.sencial.com.br/teste/teste_radio_2.html) / 
[link3 - working without radio](http://www.sencial.com.br/teste/teste_radio_3.html)

Following sideroxylon tip, I did, but no success. I'm very bad with javascript :-(

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.div_entrega_outro').hide();
    if($('.iradio_square_green:first').hasClass('checked')) {

            $('.div_entrega_outro').show();
    };
});
```

Comment: Maybe bootstrap is messing up the things?

Comment: With the edit, you still need to add a click function - something like `$(document').on('click', '.iradio_square_green', function() {`, and then add an `else` at the end of the conditional, to hide the div in the alternative case.

Comment: Man, i tried all the 3 javascript codes in the link below, but nothing.. I think the logic is correct. Please, take a look [link](http://www.sencial.com.br/teste/teste_radio_2.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be working with your code. I didn't change anything. Maybe something on your page is messing it up?

```js
$('.div_entrega_outro').hide();
$("input[id$='entrega_outro']").click(function() {
  $('.div_entrega_outro').show();
});

$("input[id$='entrega_mesmo']").click(function() {
  $('.div_entrega_outro').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="outro_endereco_entrega" id="entrega_mesmo" type="radio" value="N"> <label for="InputName">Entregar no endereço de cadastro</label><br>
<input name="outro_endereco_entrega" id="entrega_outro" type="radio" value="S"> <label for="InputName">Entregar em outro endereço</label>

<div class="div_entrega_outro">
  bla bla bla
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you left out the a symbol to you div

```
<div class="div_entrega_outro" >
    bla bla bla
</div> <-----here
```

I added to your js file

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name='outro_endereco_entrega']").click(function() {
    if ($("#entrega_mesmoYes").is(":checked")) {
      $("#div_entrega_outro").show();
    } else {
      $("#div_entrega_outro").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="chkYes">
  <input type="radio" name="outro_endereco_entrega" id="entrega_mesmoYes" /> Entregar no endereço de cadastro
</label>
<label for="chkNo">
  <input type="radio" name="outro_endereco_entrega" id="entrega_mesmoNo" checked /> Entregar em outro endereço
</label>


<div id="div_entrega_outro" style="display: none">
  bla bla bla
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly didnt work. If I use a simple link instead the radiobutton, works fine...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.

```js
$('.div_entrega_outro').hide();
$("input[name='outro_endereco_entrega']").click(function() {
  if ($(this).val() === 'N') {
    $('.div_entrega_outro').show();
  } else {
    $('.div_entrega_outro').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="outro_endereco_entrega" id="entrega_mesmo" type="radio" value="N"> <label for="InputName">Entregar no endereço de cadastro</label><br>
<input name="outro_endereco_entrega" id="entrega_outro" type="radio" value="S"> <label for="InputName">Entregar em outro endereço</label>

<div class="div_entrega_outro">
  bla bla bla
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly didnt work. Is necessary to keep $(document).ready(function()  ?

Comment: No.  If you add `console.log('clicked')` inside the click function the function, do you get anything?

Comment: Where I get something? In the chrome inspector? Apparently nothing happened

Comment: So the click is not being registered?  Are the radio buttons dynamically added?  Try `$(document).on('click', 'input[name=outro_endereco_entrega]', function() {`

Comment: Still not working. Without the `$(document).ready(function() {` the div became visible in the page load. Here is the page tests: [link1](http://www.sencial.com.br/teste/teste_radio_1.html) / [link2](http://www.sencial.com.br/teste/teste_radio_2.html) / [link3 - working without radio](http://www.sencial.com.br/teste/teste_radio_3.html)

Comment: Yeap! As I suspected, the problem was with bootstrap.js `<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`. But still the question remain: how can I make this work once I need bootstrap on the page...?

Comment: I'd scrap the radio buttons and just check which of the parent divs (`iradio_square_green`) has the class `checked' and then hide/show the other div accordingly

Comment: Ooohh! Please, how can i verify which one is checked once is a div element without value?

Comment: Add a click function to the class`iradio_square_green`, then, onclick, do something like `if($('.iradio_square_green:first').hasClass('checked') {`

Comment: At the bottom of my question I edit with the piece of code which I update my page, but still not work. I'm bad with javascript...